# body-parser doesn't work and req.body returns empty

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, ejs, body-parser

I have an ejs template with a simple form with just a value:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Cambia email</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form action="/user/cambia-email" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name"email" id="email">
    <input type="submit" value="Modifica email">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

In my app.js I tried to call a *console.log(req.body)* but it returns empty "{}".
This is my app.js code:

```
const fs = require("fs");
const express = require("express");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const { verifyToken, signToken, deleteToken } = require("./middleware/user-auth");
require("dotenv").config();

const app = express();

app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());

app.get("/user/cambia-email", verifyToken, (req, res) => {
  res.render("cambia-email");
});

app.post("/user/cambia-email", verifyToken, (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.headers);
  console.log(req.body);
  res.send("Hai richiesto la modifica dell'email. Sei autorizzato!");
});

app.get("/login", signToken, (req, res) => {
  res.send();
});

app.get("/logout", deleteToken, (req, res) => {
  res.send("Logout effettuato")
});

app.get("/user/profile", verifyToken, (req, res) => {
  const tema = req.user.tema;
  res.render("profile", { tema });
});

app.get("/user/message", verifyToken, (req, res) => {
  res.send("Sei autorizzato!");
});

app.listen(3000, () => console.log("Server in ascolto sulla porta 3000..."));
```

In other questions a lot of people said to use *app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));* but nothing change.
I tried *.json()* too but nothing seems change. By the way I tried console.log(req.headers) too and it returns: *origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'* so urlencoded should work but it doesn't.
Any solution? Thanks

Comment: have you tried express "built in" body parser? `app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));` (I think that's how you use it)

Comment: Hi, I used it but it doesn’t work neither. Than I read that for the body-parser you have to download the module separately and from the express one.

Answer (score 1):

Ok guys I solved my own problem. I post my solution for anyone who need:
basically I rewrote my form in my ejs file so:

```
<form action="/user/cambia-email" method="post">
    <label form="email">Email:</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Modifica email">
  </form>
```

The problem was that the name doesn't have an equal after (name"email" instead of name="email").

The way I used to parse the body is:
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

I suggest to set extended to true to avoid any warning but only the value of body.

Comment: yes I was changing my answer. I was editing that right now.